# GIT un-rollback a commit

Tags: git

I did a commit and push on my git repo.

I then needed to rollback that commit which I did like this:

```
git reset --hard b1b5768c9687455f01bab242ff177a5ee403104f
```

Is it possible to find the SHA of the first commit? and go back to it again?

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend. or just use `git reset origin/master --hard` (assuming the remote in named origin, and the branch you are using is master)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git log -g` or `git reflog` to see the reflog -- the log of all of the values that a given `HEAD` has taken on.  Think of it as a chronological history of HEAD rather than a checkin history.

Once you find it you can `git reset` back to it (possibly after creating a branch specifically to point to it) or cherry pick part of it that you want.

Comment: git reflog is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The direct way (immediately after) would be

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

This just takes the previous reference from the reflog for HEAD